# Tomcat 7 service.bat file is missing

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-services, tomcat7

I like to use command line to install Tomcat as a Windows service. There should be the *service.bat* file for this purpose. But it is missing from Tomcat 7.0.37 and 7.0.39. 
We can not use Windows installer for embedded, so this is not an option.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you sure you have downloaded the right package?

From the [download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) for the latest Tomcat 7 version (7.0.39 at the moment of writing this) choose depending on your needs:

- 32-bit Windows zip
- 64-bit Windows zip

Both packages have *service.bat* **in the *bin* directory**.

Also on the [download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi#Mirrors) read the README file for packaging information. It explains what every distribution contains.

---

### UPDATE

From the README file for packaging information (emphasis mine):

> *apache-tomcat-[version].zip or .tar.gz*
>          **Base distribution**. These distributions **do not include the Windows service** wrapper nor the compiled APR/native library for Windows.
>
> *apache-tomcat-[version]-windows-x86.zip*
>          **32-bit Windows specific** distribution that **includes the Windows service** wrapper and the compiled APR/native library for use with
>   32-bit JVMs on both 32 and 64 bit Windows platforms.
>
> *apache-tomcat-[version]-windows-x64.zip*
>          **64-bit Windows specific** distribution that **includes the Windows service** wrapper and the compiled APR/native library for use with
>   64-bit JVMs on x64 Windows platforms.

You may also find it useful reading the *RUNNING.txt* file, which is available in every distribution. It contains important details about installing/configuring/running Apache Tomcat and also Windows and *nix specific instructions.

Tomcat is a Java application. So it is cross-platform. But **if you want/need to utilize Windows specific features**, like Windows services in your case, then you should download the Windows specific distribution.

---

### Other thoughts

I myself on my Windows machine use "**Base distribution**" (i.e. not Windows specific, but an ordinary ZIP file available on the download page under *Binary Distributions => Core*) without any problem whatsoever, because I prefer not to bother with installations (i.e. running the installer), but just to simply unpack the distribution to the desired directory and manually configure it using the related [*config* files](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html). It's so much easier and convenient both to install (just unpack) and delete the installation (just delete without running any uninstaller), and it's more portable. Plus this way you can install multiple versions of Tomcat on the same machine (in case you need this for some development/testing reasons).

Here is a very useful step-by-step tutorial with some nice illustrations and explanations:

- [How to Install Apache Tomcat 7/8 (on Windows, Mac, Ubuntu) and Get
  Started with Java Servlet
  Programming](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html)

Comment: I downloaded cross-platform one: apache-tomcat-7.0.39.zip. It does not have it under bin. what is the difference than xxxx-windows-x86/64.zip Thanks.

Comment: Running tomcat as a service on Windows does not prevent you from running multiple instances of tomcat. The service how to describes how to do this https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Answer (score 10):

In the [official web site](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), under core. Don't download the version tagged **zip**. Download the version tagged **32-bit Windows zip** or **64-bit Windows zip**. You will find **Service.bat** under Bin

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @PeterFoti, I don't think including the contents of that `service.bat` would do any good in this case :)

Comment: This answer should be the correct one, i had the same issue because i didn't download the right zip